# Open a text file with jsp button click and java

Tags: java, jsp, button, text, click

am asking this question after some research. Am trying to open a text file located in my local maching with java and jsp. ie when I click a button in jsp it should open the text file for me. Could some one please help me on this.

Hi, Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class Start extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {         
    try {         
      if ((new File("C:\\Debug\\log20.txt")).exists()) {     
                Process p = Runtime
                   .getRuntime()
                   .exec("C:\\Debug\\log20.txt");
                p.waitFor();

            } else {

                System.out.println("File is not exists");

            }

            System.out.println("Done");

          } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
    }
```

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>       
    <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.abc.def.LogFile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logfile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01   
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<% String status=""; %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>EMC eLicensing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/headerDefault.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/bodyTemplate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/footer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/helperClasses.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/railPanel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_ngoe/buttons.css" />
</head>
<body>


<!-- Header Start -->
<div class="parentheader">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            <a href="#home" title="E">E</a>
        </h1>
        <div id="header-text-position">
            <div id="header-text"><a     
href="home.jsp"></a></div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Header End -->

<br>
<br>

<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <!-- START CONTENT -->
        <td>
            <P>
            lmgrd options
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <FORM action="start" METHOD="GET">

                            <table   
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Start/Stop/Reread</td>
                                    <td><input type=submit name=txtSubmit1 id=txtSubmit value="Start" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                </FORM>

                <FORM action="stop" METHOD="GET">

                            <table 
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Start/Stop/Reread</td>
                                    <td><input type=submit name=txtSubmit2 id=txtSubmit value="Stop" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                </FORM>

                <FORM action="logfile" METHOD="GET">

                            <table 
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>LOGFILE</td>
                                    <td><input type=submit name=txtSubmit3 id=txtSubmit value=LOG /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                </FORM>
                <form action="start" method="GET"  
enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <input type="file" name="file" 
value=text />
                        <input type="submit" />

</form>
                <form action="status" method=GET>   

                <BR>
                <BR>
                <input type=submit name=Submit id=txtSubmit  
value=Status>
            </form>
            <BR>
            status: <%=status %>
                <p>
            <p>
            <p> 
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what did you try so far.post your code

Comment: File is located on your machine. And where is server running ? Is it also running on your machine ?

Comment: yes both are on my machine .I mean server is also running on my machine. Any help is appreciated. I posted the code

Comment: Why are you using System.out.println in a servlet? That's for console programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could you try it like this if you want to browse the file in an external program

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Path\\to\\notepad.exe C:\\Debug\\log20.txt");
```

And if you want to browse the file in web page you could try the following:

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
File file = new File("C:\\Debug\\log20.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line = "";
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I don't have any notepad.exe. All am doing is am running an exe file which will create a log.txt file in some location. Now I want to open that .txt file with a button click on jsp page

Comment: Notepad is a text editor that is preinstalled with every version of windows I have head about it.
You propably can find it `C:\\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`

Comment: Hi fujy, thanks so much. It worked and am able to open the txt file now. As I told that am starting an exe file with java code which stores a log file in some location. What I have to do is have to run this exe file from a jsp button which am able to do. The problem am having is there is a file which I have to browse from the webpage and then run the exe file. exe file will run with all the details of the file that is browsed. Am able to browse the file too but not sure how to connect the browsed file with the exe file. Hope I did not confuse.

Comment: Excuse me, I tried to understand you, but I couldn't, if you want to browse the file with notepad then use the above solution, it you want to browse the file in your web page, then read its content and send it in the response

Comment: ******* it you want to browse the file in your web page, then read its content and send it in the response*****This is what exactly I want. Could you please provide me a sample. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are welcome .. If you don't mind could you make the answer as acceptable, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Acceptable. Am not sure how to make it acceptable. Am just commenting here as acceptable.If not plz let me know where I need to make it as acceptable.

Comment: Also could you please help me in one more thing.I have to select a file by browsing it and then when I click the submit button it should run the .exe file which has details of the browsed file.I was able to write code for the browse file and .exe file but not sure where exactly I should link these two.When I browse the file and click the button to run .exe file its working but if am selecting a wrong file and then running the .exe file its still working which is incorrect. I can post my code if required.

Comment: As you said you already have two JSPs, you could make the first one for browsing the files with some `form` element with an action to the second JSP    
  
`<form action="second.jsp" method="GET">`    
..  
`</form>`    
  
And when the user submit the form, he redirected to the second JSP that open the exe file

Comment: Check a simple example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm